# how to establish secure connection using ssl between html5 website and wbeserver

Tags: php, security, ssl, mysql-workbench, hybrid-mobile-app

Please I have a android hybrid app which mean i'v build it with html5,javascript and css. and with it i consult some informations from a database through php . this database and php files i've hosted them in x10hosting.com website . 
but i want to make the connection between my app and the database (php)secure . i want to use ssl , but i don't know how to do it,  I've searching for like a weak , and i'm here so please help me because this is my final project . please any tutorials or links i'll be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

I assume it should be enough if you configure your HTTP server to allow SSL connections (have you done anything in this direction?) and then use it by simply connecting to "HTTPS" instead of "HTTP".

One more thing is that your app should check the validity of the certificate of the server - otherwise you are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I don't have experience on that. please if you have any links or tutorials on how to create http server , i'll be very thankful

Comment: please , i need to understand , so i must configure a http server like apache and keep it in my personnal computer or what ?

Comment: Hi, can you specify the type of web container running on the server? Also do you have access/control to the server?

Comment: now i'm working on my local wamp , i've created a ssl certificate so now i can access localhost by https and it worked. but i don't know how to make connection because in my androdi when i replace the http by https in xmlhttprequest it won't work , this is my post but i didn't get any answer .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819261/connect-android-hybrid-app-to-https-server